# Import XML file into MySQL using a simple PHP script

Tags: php, xml, import, simplexml

I have tried so many help pages on multpl sites/forums and am still struggling here.

I am looking to simply import XML data from an online URL/file into a MySQL database.

The https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-load-xml-data-into-mysql-using-php/ worked with the sample data though the XML data feed I have to work with is structured differently.

This is the XML data feed I have...

```
<STOREITEMS>
        <PRODUCT ITEM='sku-01' NAME='This Is Title 1'>
            <STOCK>
                In Stock
            </STOCK>
        </PRODUCT>
        
        
        
        <PRODUCT ITEM='sku-02' NAME='This Is Title 2'>
            <STOCK>
                In Stock
            </STOCK>
        </PRODUCT>
        
        
        
        <PRODUCT ITEM='sku-03' NAME='This Is Title 3'>
            <STOCK>
                No Stock.
            </STOCK>
        </PRODUCT>
    </STOREITEMS>
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

I have used the geekforgeeks code as below...

```
<?php
 
// Connect to database
// Server - localhost
// Username - root
// Password - empty
// Database name = xmldata
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "empty", "xmldata");
 
$affectedRow = 0;
 
// Load xml file else check connection
$xml = simplexml_load_file("xmltest.xml")
    or die("Error: Cannot create object");
 
// Assign values
foreach ($xml->children() as $row) {

    $product = $row->product;
    $stock = $row->stock;
     

    $sql = "INSERT INTO xtrader(
        SKU, stock) VALUES ('"
        . $product . "','" . $stock . "')";     
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     
    if (! empty($result)) {
        $affectedRow ++;
    } else {
        $error_message = mysqli_error($conn) . "\n";
    }
}
?>
 
<center><h2>GEEKS GOR GEEKS</h2></center>
<center><h1>XML Data storing in Database</h1></center>
<?php
if ($affectedRow > 0) {
    $message = $affectedRow . " records inserted";
} else {
    $message = "No records inserted";
}
 
?>
<style>
    body { 
        max-width:550px;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    .affected-row {
        background: #cae4ca;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: #bdd6bd 1px solid;
        border-radius: 2px;
        color: #6e716e;
    }
    .error-message {
        background: #eac0c0;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: #dab2b2 1px solid;
        border-radius: 2px;
        color: #5d5b5b;
    }
</style>
 
<div class="affected-row">
    <?php  echo $message; ?>
</div>
 
<?php if (! empty($error_message)) { ?>
 
<div class="error-message">
    <?php echo nl2br($error_message); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Nothing is importing.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: I have attempted several methods of trying to import the unusual  formatted XML data. I do not want to flood the query with multiple methods I have used and failed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$product = $row->product;
```

There is no `$row->product` because the `<PRODUCT>` element is itself the row. You want the attribute named `ITEM` in that element:

```
$attributes = $row->attributes();
$sku = (string) $attributes['ITEM'];
```

Or:

```
$sku = (string) $row->attributes()['ITEM'];
```

Or just:

```
$sku = (string) $row['ITEM'];
```

Also note that `$row->STOCK` will get you everything in that attribute, *including whitespace*:

```
$stock = (string) $row->STOCK;
var_dump($stock);
```

Yields:

```
string(38) "
            In Stock
        "
```

This is probably not what you want, so `trim()` the excess:

```
$stock = trim((string) $row->STOCK);
```

Other concerns:

- Some of your items use `No Stock` and some use `No Stock.` with a period. If you base conditionals on this, you're gonna have a bad time. This value probably should be a simple integer representation, so the "no stock" condition would be simply `<STOCK>0</STOCK>`.
- If you're going to put the SKU and NAME in attributes, you might as well put the stock in an attribute too, like `<PRODUCT ITEM='sku-01' NAME='This Is Title 1' STOCK='0'>`. The only reason you'd put the stock as a separate element is if you can have more than one value per item, which doesn't seem to make sense here.
- Don't ignore your SQL injections, that's a big deal.

Comment: The XML feed is an external one, I have no control over the format of the feed and yes, the STOCK field is either "In Stock" or "No Stock." with the period unfortunatly.

Comment: `$row->['ITEM']` is not valid PHP syntax, the `[...]` is instead of `->`, not as well as it; I've [updated that example in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75793287/revisions).

Comment: Oops, typo'ed, thx.